# ToC figures and text overlap

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using XeLaTeX and memoir to write a longer text with several parts, chapters and sections. When printing the \tableofcontents I get a spacing problem with 2-figure numbers almost overlapping the relevant section name, as per enclosed picture.  I am aware that
the memoir manual has a section dedicated to this theme, but the most part of it is doubledutch to me. Is there any easy way to avoid this problem?

[image: A partial view of my ToC]

Comment: related question: (word-overlap-in-toc-with-memoir-class-and-part-subdivision)[http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31294/]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to say something like

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \addtolength{\cftsectionnumwidth}{.5em}
  \addtolength{\cftsubsectionnumwidth}{.5em}
}
```

or even `1em`: experiment with the added width. The code should go in the preamble.

The relevant section in the manual is 9.2.2

Comment: Your help was much welcome and very appreciated :)) Thank you!

Comment: @PaulAgos Please, read the [FAQ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) particularly about upvoting and accepting answers. Nobody forces you to do it, but it's how contributions are rewarded.

Comment: I apologize — didn't know that. I read the FAQ, which is cryptic enough about this subject and I don't know if it possible to vote "a posteriori". Next time I'll be more careful. Thanks again

Comment: @PaulAgos You can upvote at any time both questions and answers as soon as your reputation is over 15 (see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation)). You can and should upvote all answers and questions that you find useful, not only answers to your questions. This helps readers in sorting out what is considered the best answer, for instance.