# Tufte book - inline spacing list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, tufte

I have a small problem with the Tufte book. I inserted the per-section numbering but then the inline spacing gets all too crowded, as in the picture.

[image: Tufte in-line overcrowded]

Any command I could use to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62688/15925 help?