# Make box with minimum width (in math mode)

Tags: boxes, width, varwidth

How can I give a box a minimal width, in math mode?  That is, I would like a command something like `\minwidth{exp}{width}`, which will always typeset `exp`, but additionally, *if* the natural length of `exp` is less than `width`, will pad it by centering it in a box of width `width`.

For instance, `$A \minwidth{i}{2em} B$` should come out like `$A \makebox[2em][c]{i} B$`; but `$A \minwidth{WXYZ}{2em} B$` should come out like `$A WXYZ B$`.

The `varwidth` package provides this variable-width functionality, but only for a minipage, not for a plain box or similar.

(The use case is for a variant of the inline TikZ arrow commands defined in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116324/1635), padding the arrow label to a minimal width, so that the arrow extends for large labels, but does not get too short when the label are short or absent.)

**Edit:** This turned out to be a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): Harish Kumar has excellently answered my real problem, without answering this specific question.  What I am now using, adapted from his answer, is:

```
\newcommand{\myto}[1][]{ \mathrel{
  \tikz[baseline={([yshift=-0.55ex]a.south)}]{%
    \node[minimum width=1.5em,align=center,inner xsep=0.3ex,inner ysep=0.15ex] (a) {$\scriptstyle #1$};
    \draw[->] (a.south west) -- ([xshift=0.6ex]a.south east);}
  }\mkern-1mu}
```

with usage as in `$A \myto[f] B$`.

I would still be interested in answers to the specific question asked, though.

Comment: Related Question: [Determine natural with of align*: varwidth uses \linewidth even though display is correct](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394945/4301).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a `tikz` only approach. Adjust `ex`s suitably.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,mathtools}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newcommand*{\ident}[1]{\texttt{\small #1}}

\tikzstyle{refines} = [->, >=open triangle 45]

\newcommand{\refi}[3]{%
  \( #1 \)
  \tikz[baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex]a.south)}]{%
  \node[minimum width=2em,align=center] (a) {$#2$};     %%<<---- width here
  \draw[refines] (a.south west) --  ([xshift=1ex]a.south east);}   %% <<---- shift here
  \(#3 \)}

\begin{document}

This is a test \refi{\ident{1}}{\text{t}}{\ident{2}}\ident{2} that continues here.

This is a test \refi{1}{\text{longer text}}{1} that continues here.

A further test \refi{j_2}{\alpha-x e^{p/q}}{a^2} with more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The magic word here is `minimum width=2em` option for the `node`. I have also used some `xshift` for the arrow head to make it more symmetric. Adjust these values as you need.

Comment: Fantastic; thankyou!  Some of the specifics of the linked question are irrelevant to my case, though, so I’ve ended up using a slightly different (maybe more generally applicable) version; see edit to question.

Answer (score 11):

`\makebox` puts its contents into a box, whose dimensions are available as `\width`, `\height`, `\depth` inside the optional arguments of `\makebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\minwidthbox}[2]{%
  \makebox[{\ifdim#2<\width\width\else#2\fi}]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  [\minwidthbox{i}{2em}]\\\relax
  [\minwidthbox{WXYZ}{2em}]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Extended example with automatic math mode and style detection:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\minwidthbox}[2]{%
  \relax
  \ifmmode
    \mathpalette{\minwidthboxmath{#1}{#2}}{}%
  \else
    \makebox[{\ifdim#2<\width\width\else#2\fi}]{#1}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\minwidthboxmath}[4]{%
  % #1: box contents
  % #2: minimum width
  % #3: math style
  % #4: unused
  \mbox{\minwidthbox{$#3#1$}{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  [\minwidthbox{i}{2em}]\\\relax
  [\minwidthbox{WXYZ}{2em}]

  \noindent
  $a\minwidthbox{i}{2em}b$\\
  $a\minwidthbox{WXYZ}{2em}b$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result of extended example]

Answer (score 7):

Pushing further Heiko's idea, but letting `mathtools` do the job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\minwidthbox}[2]{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\mathmakebox
  \else
    \expandafter\makebox
  \fi
  [\ifdim#2<\width\width\else#2\fi]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
[\minwidthbox{i}{2em}]\\\relax
[\minwidthbox{WXYZ}{2em}]

\noindent
$a\minwidthbox{i}{2em}b$\\
$a\minwidthbox{WXYZ}{2em}b$

\noindent
$A\xrightarrow{i}B$\\
$A\xrightarrow{\minwidthbox{i}{3em}}B$% exaggerated

\end{document}
```

[image]