# Tikz matrix arrows alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, tikz-matrix

I have a problem that I cannot solve for myself.

The following code produces the following image, which I do not really like.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=0em, column sep=4em, minimum width=2em]
  { 0 & \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z}^2          & 0 \\
      & (\alpha_0, \alpha_1)       & (-\alpha_0, \alpha_1) &   \\
      &                            & \beta_{01}            & 0 \\ };
\path[>=stealth, ->]
    (m-1-1.east|-m-1-2) edge node [above] {\scriptsize$d_{-1}$} (m-1-2.west|-m-1-2)
    (m-1-2.east|-m-1-2) edge node [above] {\scriptsize$d_{ 0}$} (m-1-3.west|-m-1-2)
    (m-1-3.east|-m-1-2) edge node [above] {\scriptsize$d_{ 1}$} (m-1-4.west|-m-1-2);
\path[>=stealth, |->]
    (m-2-2.east|-m-2-2) edge (m-2-3.west|-m-2-2);
\path[>=stealth, |->]
    (m-3-3.east|-m-3-3) edge (m-3-4.west|-m-3-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image: Old]

What I want to achieve is having arrows aligned, more or less as in the following image

[image: New]

Does someone have some hint?
I prefer to use tikz, but any other package can be welcome.

Comment: instead of `minimum width=2em` put `nodes={text width=1.5cm}` (tweak if you wish).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately this alignes the text on the left, which is even uglier than before :S

Comment: Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction. Indeed this almost solves my problem: `nodes={text width=1.5cm, align=center}`. The problem is with the last 0 on the right, which gets too distant from the arrow.

Comment: I managed to solve it with the use of the column styler, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @percusse for pointing me in the right direction to find the solution.

Styling column by column is a solution to this problem (altought not as elegant as I expected).
The point is to modify each column definition to obtain what I want, so for example

```
column 2/.style={nodes={text width=1.5cm, align=center}}
```

The final code is the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=0em, column sep=4em, column 2/.style={nodes={text width=1.5cm, align=center}},column 3/.style={nodes={text width=1.5cm, align=center}}]
  { 0 & \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z}^2          & 0\\
      & (\alpha_0, \alpha_1)       & (-\alpha_0, \alpha_1) & \\
      &                            & \beta_{01}            & 0\\ };
\path[>=stealth, ->]
    (m-1-1.east|-m-1-2) edge node [above] {\scriptsize$d_{-1}$} (m-1-2.west|-m-1-2)
    (m-1-2.east|-m-1-2) edge node [above] {\scriptsize$d_{ 0}$} (m-1-3.west|-m-1-2)
    (m-1-3.east|-m-1-2) edge node [above] {\scriptsize$d_{ 1}$} (m-1-4.west|-m-1-2);
\path[>=stealth, |->]
    (m-2-2.east|-m-2-2) edge (m-2-3.west|-m-2-2);
\path[>=stealth, |->]
    (m-3-3.east|-m-3-3) edge (m-3-4.west|-m-3-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Unless you use `TiKZ` for some other reason. There is no need to use it to obtain your diagram.

With help from ["The Comprehensive LaTeX symbols list"](http://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive) (for `\xrightarrow` and `\xmapsto`) and egreg's answer to [Make box with minimum width (in math mode)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188343/make-box-with-minimum-width-in-math-mode) (for `\minwidthbox`) is possible to write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,empheq,mathtools}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\minwidthbox}[2]{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\mathmakebox
  \else
    \expandafter\makebox
  \fi
  [\ifdim#2<\width\width\else#2\fi]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
0 & \xrightarrow{\minwidthbox{d_{-1}}{3em}}    
   & \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}
   & \xrightarrow{\minwidthbox{d_0}{3em}} 
   & \mathbb{Z}^2 
   & \xrightarrow{\minwidthbox{d_1}{3em}} 
   & 0 \\
   &  
   & (\alpha_0,\alpha_1) 
   & \xmapsto{\minwidthbox{}{3em}} 
   & (-\alpha_0,\alpha_1) 
   & 
   & \\
   & 
   & 
   & 
   & \beta_{01} & \xmapsto{\minwidthbox{}{3em}}  & 0 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could also define an `\Arrow` command of fixed width and variable style and let the `\matrix` manage the alignment and column widths instead of doing it manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\Arrow}[2][->]{%
    \tikz[baseline=-0.7ex, x=2cm, #1]
        \path (0,0) edge node [above] {\scriptsize#2} (1,0);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=0em]
  { 0 & \Arrow{$d_{-1}$} & \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} & \Arrow{$d_{0}$} & \mathbb{Z}^2          & \Arrow{$d_{1}$} & 0 \\
      &                  & (\alpha_0, \alpha_1)       & \Arrow[|->]{}   & (-\alpha_0, \alpha_1) &                 &   \\
      &                  &                            &                 & \beta_{01}            &  \Arrow[|->]{}  & 0 \\ };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Compiled result]

Comment: don't nest tikzpictures. They are always trouble.

Comment: You mean styles might leak from the parent picture to the child picture? That doesn't seem to be a problem in this simple example, but of course it's good to be aware that it _might_ be the cause of strange problems. I guess it would be possible to achieve this without nesting if the `matrix of nodes` key were removed.